# fblualib installation in Ubunt16.04

Tags: c++11, pytorch, torch, fbconnect, autoreconf

I am trying to install `fblualib` from this [link](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fblualib).

When I run `./install_all.sh` inside `fblualib`, I have errors as

```
+ echo Building folly
Building folly
+ echo

+ cd /tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly
+ autoreconf -ivf
autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required
```

According to last discussion [here](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/613), there is a discussion as "autotools based build system has been removed from Folly in favor of CMake, so you'll need to build Folly with CMake rather than autotools." so I go to folly folder

```
/tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/build and try to build using `cmake`.
```

Then I have errors as

```
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.cpp.o
In file included from /tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.h:33:0,
                 from /tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.cpp:16:
/tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly/SharedMutex.h: In static member function ‘static void folly::threadlocal_detail::StaticMetaBase::onThreadExit(void*)’:
/tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly/SharedMutex.h:457:33: error: ‘*((void*)& rlock +10)’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Werror=maybe-uninitialized]
         !tryUnlockSharedDeferred(token.slot_)) {
                                 ^
/tmp/fblualib-build.zofU4g/folly/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.cpp:169:31: note: ‘*((void*)& rlock +10)’ was declared here
       SharedMutex::ReadHolder rlock(nullptr);
                               ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/build.make:1886: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/detail/ThreadLocalDetail.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

The error is happening in `SharedMutex.h`, what could be worng>